# Cannot scroll down past certain point - iPhone X compatibility issue

Tags: html, css, compatibility

On one of our test sites: https://notts-laod.verseonecloud.com/

For some reason, on an iPhone X (and possibly others), you cannot scroll down past the 'news' section of the site. See the attached screenshot for details.

[image]

When viewing on an iPhone simulation on my macbook Pro on safari, the issue does not occur. Would anyone happen to know why?

There's an overflow-x applied to news section that means you can scroll horizontally through the news images, but that shouldn't affect it.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Have you tried on the iOS simulator in Xcode? Using safari shouldn’t be used as a simulator, it’s just changing the browser window size and user agent.

Comment: I haven't actually, and that sounds like a good idea. Is there any other way of simulating it? I don't think my employer uses compatibility software like browserstack